# angular unit test - how to mock router.config.data

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So i have the following code in my component:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}

ngOnInit(){
module = this.router.config[0].data['env'].module
}
```

Now when running my unit tests with Jasmine and Karma, I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'env' of undefined
```

Basically, the config.data.env is an environment variable that comes from another component to my component in the libs folder.
So i need to mock the env variable.

That's what i tried in my spec file:

```
    const fakeData = {
        data: {
          env: {
            module: 'myModule',
          }
        },
    }
```

and on the TestBed.configureTestingModule imports:

```
 imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes, fakeData),
]
```

The second argument on the withRoutes is extraOptions, But it doesn't work.

How can i mock the environment variable and set it on the router.config?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `routes` variable, attach the data property to the first element and remove `fakeData` from `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes, fakeData)`.

Something like this:

```
const routes = [{ 
                  path: 'xyz', 
                  component: YourComponent, 
                  data: {
                    env: {
                      module: 'mockModule'
                    }
                  } 
                }];
```